# Phrases that mean "I have no idea"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms

What phrases can be used interchangably with “I have no idea”?

I request two types of answers:

- Polite forms of saying it.
- Casual forms of saying it.

"I have no idea" seems simple and traditional. It doesn't show any emotions of the speaker in responding to the question.

Sometimes I feel that responding just "I have no idea/ I don't know"
is not in a proper situation when I talk to my boss.

I also need a more playful expression when I say it ""I have no idea/ I don't know" to my friends.

Comment: Wouldn't "I don't know" cover polite and casual?

Comment: Casual equivalents could be "Search me" (with the emphasis on _me_) or "I haven't the foggiest" (_idea_ being implied).

Comment: To your boss: "That's a great question. Let me see if I can find the answer for you."

Comment: To your friends: "And you think I know this because...."

Answer (score 2):

Although I think it would be a relief for many bosses to  just hear an honest 'I have no idea', these polite alternatives might work for you:

> "Great question, let me look into it, and I'll get back to you."
>
> "I'm not sure, let me look into it, and I'll get back to you."

Casually, you could say:

> "I (really) have no clue."

If you want to emphasise the fact you really have no clue whatsoever, I think you could say:

> "I cannot for the life of me understand why/how..."

- My English is far from perfect yet. Please check all my suggestions before using them ;)